# Print specific element of json object of an array using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am describing a AWS security group and passing the output by `jq` in order to get all the CIDRs of the inbound rules.

I have reached so far:

```
▶ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-123456789 | jq '.SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions[0].IpRanges'
[
  {
    "CidrIp": "11.22.33.44/32",
    "Description": "Something"
  },
  {
    "CidrIp": "22.33.44.12/32",
    "Description": "Something else"
  },
  {
    "CidrIp": "22.11.33.55/32",
    "Description": "Something different"
  },
]
```

I know I can `grep` but is there a way to get just the `CidrIp` from each `json` element of this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, change your pipeline to

```sh
jq -r '.SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions[0].IpRanges[].CidrIp'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cCqn6gXGz7)

Note that I also added the `-r` flag which makes the output raw text instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq '.SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions[0].IpRanges | values[].CidrIp'
```

this seemed to work as well.